# Error in configuring virtual box to ADB

Tags: android, android-emulator, adb

I have setup virtual box for android emulator. Everything was fine till now, but when I am trying to connect to add to virtual box it is throwing me the message:

```
unable to connect to 10.0.2.15/24:5555
```

I have Win 7 machine

Please help me to resolve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am answering the question so that any one can use it if they similar error

Removed the virtual device and installed the again. This time I changed the network adaptor from NAT to Bridge Adapter in settings.

Pressed Alt+F1 and typed netcfg, Noted down the IP and got successfully connected from command prompt using adb connect to IP.